"generative" module not found but it is installed
I am trying to build an AI model with SPADE, sources i found uses the following line to import it
from generative.networks.nets.spade_network import SPADE_Net

I have done
pip install generative

however when i tried running the import, it gave the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'generative'

I tried using the --user flag for the pip install, this time i know for certain that it is installed as when i run pip show generative, it gave this output
Name: generative
Version: 0.0.0
Summary: Build cross-modal and multi-modal applications on the cloud
Home-page: https://github.com/jina-ai/jina/
Author: Jina AI
Author-email: hello@jina.ai
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: aiofiles, aiohttp, aiostream, cryptography, docarray, docarray, docker, fastapi, filelock, grpcio, grpcio-health-checking, grpcio-reflection, lz4, numpy, packaging, pathspec, prometheus-client, protobuf, pydantic, python-multipart, pyyaml, requests, uvicorn, websockets
Required-by:

Can anyone help solve this problem?
